Is there a better CR equivalent?
I’ve been asking questions on this site about monster creation/alteration, and people have been telling me that the Pathfinder/3.5e CR system is broken. So I’ve been wondering, is there a better alternative?

Is there a better system than CR? No.
Fundamentally, CR is broken because there's just too much variety in what monsters can do:

do they have spells (or functional equivalents)?

are the spells combat-useful or more flavorful?
do the have one big spell or multiple small spells?
what level of spells do they have?


do they have a "schtick" besides "hit people with a stick"?

consider the cloaker, to an extent a living trap - its schtick is "hide on the ceiling" with a side of "damage to it can damage your friends".


for martial NPCs:

ranged or melee?
one big attack or several small attacks?
do the attacks have secondary effects (poison, disease, etc.)?


are they tank-ey?

HP or AC tank?
"special" tank (eg., regeneration)?
is there a way to reduce the tank-ey-ness?


do they shut down or significantly hamper a particular class/archetype?

golems largely shut down a lot of casters.
creatures immune to sneak attack really hurt rogues.


are they expected to have terrain advantages?

flying or aquatic creatures frequently fall into this.
creatures with special movement types (eg., burrowing) can often fall into this, too.


etc., etc., etc.

Trying to create a system that takes all of that into account and provide a single number that reliably orders monsters (and traps, etc.) into an easy <-> hard scale is impossible. And, you'll see that if you apply the Monster Creation guidelines to published monsters: a lot will match, but some will be a CR or two (or more?) off from the guidelines. In fact, the very first sentence of the guidelines is:

Creating a monster is part science and part art.

CR is a rough guide for GMs to use to start finding an appropriate challenge for a given party. A CR 1 creature is likely to be easier - on average - for a party to defeat than a CR 2 creature, and very likely to be easier than a CR 5 creature. And, a party of 3rd level PCs will likely mop the floor with a CR 1 creature but have to be at least a little careful handling a CR 5 one. But: there will be exceptions, especially for "this" party in "this" campaign.
Is there a better process than CR? Yes.
Unfortunately, the process is "playtest". Fundamentally, the only way to truly determine how difficult it is to defeat a given creature (or overcome a given trap, etc.) is to playtest it: run a lot of parties through the encounter, using a lot of different builds and (ideally) a lot of different players.
So, what do I do with this?
Accept that CR is a useful tool for getting a rough idea of the challenge an encounter will provide, but that it can be very wrong.
Think of it like an axe: useful for getting the tree into pieces that are small enough to work with, but not the tool you're going to use to carve the fine details.
Don't sweat a point or two of CR, especially once the PCs are past level 2 or so (mostly because most PCs' power takes a pretty big jump from level 1 to 2). It'll mostly come out in the wash.
And, as you GM, you'll get a feel both for monstrous abilities that have an outsized effect on the challenge they present and for how "this" party can handle them.

I would like to add that basic playtesting does not require more than one person. You can learn a lot about how well homebrewed encounters work by just playing against yourself. Sure, maybe a real player might come up with a really smart move you didn't consider that trivializes the encounter. But that's good for them. What you really want to avoid is the frustration of building an encounter the players can't reasonably beat with what they have. And playtesting against yourself can ensure that this isn't the case.

OK, maybe one case where you got to be careful with relying on playtesting against yourself are "puzzle" encounters that can only be beat if you know how. Like exploiting a certain damage vulnerability or using an obscure game mechanic. In that case it might be difficult to predict when (or if) the players will figure out the "trick" on their own.

@Philipp: I remember an article by AngryGM where he detailed building an encounter, and notably mentioned that the GM should try to run the "idealized" party through the encounter, with an eye toward detecting particularly salient (and undesirable) things that could happen, such as the barbarian/sorcerer one-shotting the boss, or the boss one-shotting the wizard. Or a fleeing NPC which the party was supposed to intercept but for which the interception would actually require extreme coordination/luck, etc... (cont.)

@Philipp: (cont.) ... Do note the emphasis on idealized party. This is to avoid overfitting the encounter with regard to the current player party, because doing somewhat negates player's agency: ie, the effect of their choices of class, feats, equipments, etc...

I agree that basic playtesting can be done solo (with the "puzzle"-type caveat @Philipp mentioned) and can be quite valuable for a GM playing with a new monster/ability/.... I don't believe that solo playtesting is sufficient for "replace the CR system we currently have", though. ... it's a great tool for "this GM at this table", but insufficient for "officially published content", I suppose.

No, and there probably can’t be
Pathfinder characters just have too much variety to be able to boil them down to a single number like that. I mean, consider 3.5e’s “that damn crab,” a monster that is wildly inappropriate at its official CR 3. My answer there demonstrates how it can kill half a party in conditions extremely favorable to that party. Partially, this is just a mistake by the authors, that you could rectify: the monstrous crab has stats better than some CR 4 or 5 monsters, so just calling in CR 5 is a huge step in the right direction. But that doesn’t really tell the whole story. Because that damn crab is almost completely neutered by the 2nd-level spell glitterdust. If you have glitterdust, it’s probably a fairly easy encounter at 3rd level. Not much else will do, but if you have that one specific spell, you’re probably golden.
This is an extremely simple scenario, and it already demonstrates the problems with the CR system. Because a lot of sorcerers and wizards will have glitterdust—it’s one of the best spells in the game for its level, so it’s super-popular spell to learn or prepare. And this is still at 2nd-level spells, which are mostly pretty straightforward—higher-level spells are not. Spells can do almost anything, which just cannot be well-described by a single number.
At the end of the day, a DM simply has to consider the actual capabilities of both party and monsters, and massage things into place. The system just isn’t balanced or consistent enough to do otherwise. There are some tools that help somewhat—CR for monsters, ECL for characters, and then adjustments, perhaps, for the classes’ tiers, can more-or-less get you into the right ballpark, usually. But in the end you still have to manually consider how things are actually going to go. The system just doesn’t have, and probably can’t have, anything better.
A more consistent and balanced system, on the other hand, can do better. D&D 4e is divisive, but one thing it has that is widely lauded is the effectiveness of the DM tools. That system can provide you a meaningful encounter-calculating scheme. But that comes at a cost: abilities have to fit into a specific, fairly-straightforward paradigm (“attack powers”) in order to make it work. You can’t match the variety of 3.5e content in a system like 4e (or if you did, you would lose the ability to create such reliable DM tools).
